# Base class pointer assigned to derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class, virtual-functions

I created base class pointer and assigned new derived class to it.

```
 class Base
{ 
public: 
    virtual void f( int ); 
    virtual void f( double ); 
    virtual void g( int i = 10 ); 
}; 

void Base::f( int )
{ 
    cout << "Base::f(int)" << endl;
} 

void Base::f( double )
{ 
    cout << "Base::f(double)" << endl;
} 

void Base::g( int i )
{
    cout << i << endl;
} 

class Derived: public Base
{ 
public: 
    void f( complex<double> ); 
    void g( int i = 20 ); 
};

void Derived::f( complex<double> )
{ 
    cout << "Derived::f(complex)" << endl;
} 

void Derived::g( int i )
{ 
    cout << "Derived::g() " << i << endl;
} 

void main()
{ 
    Base b; 
    Derived d; 
    Base* pb = new Derived; 
    b.f(1.0); 
    d.f(1.0); 
    pb->f(1.0); 
    b->g();
    d->g();
    pb->g(); 
    delete pb; 
}
```

Result is:

```
Base::f(double) 
Derived::f(complex) 
Base::f(double) 
10 
Derived::g() 20 
Derived::g() 10
```

Results for b and d are expected. pb->f(1.0) calls Base function f(double), but pb->g() seems to call Derived class function g but using parameter i=10 from Base class. Why?

Comment: Why? Because you're using the `Base` interface statically, the dispatch to `Derived::pb` happens only at runtime.

Comment: `delete pb;` causes undefined behaviour, since Base does not have a virtual destructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerrek SB said it all in the comment, I will detail it a bit.

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954654/4926357), the mechanism of resolving default function parameters occurs at compile time. When the compiler sees `pb->g();`, knowing that `pb` is a pointer of type `Base*`, it consults the declaration of `Base::g`, that is

```
virtual void g( int i = 10);
```

It concludes:

1- The missing parameter `i` should be set to 10. This is a compile-time decision.

2- The method is declared *virtual*, which means that the actually invoked method depends on what `pb` will be pointing-to at run time. The compiler sets the mechanism to dispatch the call to `g` at runtime (usually through an indirection via the vtable). Since at runtime it happens that pb is actually pointing to an object of type `Derived`, the method `Derived::g` is called.